# Passing refs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

In my `App` component, I have 2 components `Navbar` and `View`. In my `Navbar` component, I have an `ExportButton` component which onClick should generate a screenshot of the `View` component by passing its ref.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const view = useRef();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar takeSnap={view}/>
      <View ref={view}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Navbar.js**

```
const Navbar = ({ takeSnap }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Lists />
      <ExportButton takeSnap={takeSnap} />
    </>
  );
};
```

**Button.js**

```
const ExportButton = ({ takeSnap }) => {
 function handleClick(takeSnap) {
    domtoimage.toBlob(takeSnap.current, {}).then(function (blob) {
      saveAs(blob, "myImage.png");
    });
  }
   return (
      <Button onClick={() => handleClick(takeSnap)} />
   );
};
```

I having some trouble passing ref of `View` to use the library dom-to-image to take a screenshot. The error says "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of undefined
    at makeNodeCopy". This might be a quick fix but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Is `View` doing any ref forwarding? I'm assuming `domtoimage` is needing a DOM element, not a component reference. See https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a `ref` for a component, a `ref` can only reference a DOM element.
When you do:

```
<View ref={view}/>
```

`ref` is a reserved keyword and it won't be passed down to your View render function.

You can use `forwardRef` to solve this problem, or simply use a different keyword such as myRef:

```
<View myRef={view}/>
```

Then when you render your `View`, you can assign this ref to the element you want the screenshot from:

```
<div ref={myRef} ...
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Can you elaborate more on this please?

Comment: In App, you render Navbar before View, therefore Navbar can't access the ref of View. I think you should pass a callback to Navbar, and let Navbar calls App, then in App you can take the snapshot